Protecting publicly accessable endpoints in Django and React
I have an endpoint
urls.py
from django.urls import path 
from . import views 

app_name = 'Main'
urlpatterns = [
    path("helloKitty/", views.helloKitty, name='helloKitty'),
]


views.py
def helloKitty(request):
    hello = pd.read_csv('static/data/helloKitty_data.csv')
    hello = hello.to_json(orient='records')
    return HttpResponse(hello)

It's currently accessible by anyone at /helloKitty and it needs to be prevented.
I use React on the front-end to access this endpoint and retrieve the data
import React from "react";
import { create } from 'zustand';
import axios from 'axios';

const kittyStore = create((set) => ({
    kitten: [],

    fetchKitty: async () => {
        const response = await axios.get('/helloKitty');
        const hello = response.data.map((h) => {
            return {
                name: h.name,
                age: h.age,
            }
        });
        set({ kitten })
    },
}));

export default kittyStore;

The endpoints /helloKitty needs to be protected from being publicly accessible, and just the React app can view and fetch the data.

You should take the tutorial on Write your first Django app. There is an excellent tutorial on Django authentication there.

Make your answer more specific as to where exactly the answer to the question would be in the tutorial.

If you don’t take a basic tutorial first, you will not understand how the framework works. Nonetheless, here is a tutorial on User authentication in Django.

I have used and worked with all the concepts in the user authentication system page. Restricting the access to the endpoint for the front-end is not shown in the django documentation.

I should point out that the user does not need to be authenticated to access the endpoint through the front-end.

"…the user does not need to be authenticated to access the endpoint through the front-end". How will the server identify the client then? The client needs to have some sort of cipher that only the server can decipher and validate. This cipher should be cryptographically secure and that brings us back to "authentication". You should reconsider your design.

I may use @permission_required() in the view function, and in the react app I would authenticate the admin or any other use I would create specifically to access those endpoints through the front-end. Hence, whenever a visitor get to the index page, they will be able to view data through the front-end and not directly through the link /helloKitty

If the user doesn't need to be authenticated to access the endpoint, then that by definition means that the endpoint is publicly accessible - who cares if you can visit it directly? It's like saying you want a webpage to show an image without allowing someone to navigate directly to the URL of that image

It's premium paid content. I have found a solution using API Keys.

Which still requires "authentication".

The content is publicly displayed without authentication, an access to the API is premium and would require an API Keys, that is the endpoint /helloKitty. Of course you would need to be a registered user to access the API Keys.

"Restricting the access to the endpoint for the front-end" That's something that is generally not possible, the frontend can't be public and store a secret at the same time. Any mechanisms to identify the frontend can be spoofed by people who are determined to do so. The API keys you talk about are just another user authentication mechanism (In the end your user has to provide the API keys for you to hit the endpoint). You're not limiting access to the frontend, you're limiting access to anyone who has an API key.

I don't think you understand the question or the suggested answer. There are two types of users (unregistered users, registered users), the unregistered user will be able to view the data through the dashboard, and the registered user upon supplying the API keys will be able access the data programmatically. The unregistered user will not able to access the endpoint /helloKitty if they can not supply the API keys.
